# Ember JS: Trigger Loading Substate for slow loading templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

According to the [**Ember docs on loading substates**](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) you can optionally create a loading route and/or loading template for Promises that might take a long time to process.

I have a situation where I am rendering a large template using lots of components and the rendering time is over 2 seconds on average.

I am sure there is a solution to the slow render time, but while I work on it, I would like to see if I can call the loading template to display while the slow template is loading.

Is there a way to do this?

I have a trivial loading page all set up (just a simple message with some animated css) and saved in my templates root folder (so it could potentially be used everywhere when needed).

Ember should automatically display this loading template- just by virtue of it being there- but again, by default, it is only when a Promise is being loaded, and not a template.

So is there a workaround (i.e hack) to get this to work?

Comment: What is causing the slow rendering? Does the route's model have a bunch of async has-many relationships? Are you sure this isn't the DOM  having trouble rendering lots of new nodes at once? It's very possible that the loading substate will have zero affect on the rendering time. It may exit the substate and hang because the DOM is choking. You could write a mixin that debounced an `isLoading` property on each component's model or collection... Just thinking out load here... :)

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte It is caused by Ember-Forms I am pretty sure, because that is the only page that is having problems on.  The page has about 30-or-so inputs/selects, and each of which are wrapped inside of components that control validation and a few other things.  Needless to say it causes a lot of noise in the DOM.  I didn't even link it up to any live model yet and already the render time is around 2.3s.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte eventually I want to create my own form components but I thought Ember-Forms would speed my productivity out of the gate... I don't even know if it is a decent library anymore though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be leading yourself off-course here with the loading substate.

My best guess at this point is that you need to address your `{{view Ember.Select}}` helpers within that template. These are terribly slow to render. I ran into this problem recently when rendering a few thousand options across 15-20 selects on a page.

Unfortunately, the DOM is usually the bottleneck of big SPAs, and you'll probably need to get creative if you want that snappy async feel everywhere in your app.

Try to reduce the number of options that are rendered, and you will speed things up.  Or, you could try another form library... Or, roll your own.

Update::

If I were you, I would consider adding a method to the `ArrayController` that dynamically creates and slowly loads the options in chunks. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
App.CollectionController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  generatedOptions: null,
  generateOptions: function () {},
  destroyOptions: function () {
    this.set('generatedOptions', null);
  }
});

App.CollectionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.generateOptions(); //slowly render
  },
  willTransition: function () {
    this.controllerFor('controller').destroyOptions(); //destroy so that when we return it will need to generate again
  }
});

{{#each generatedOptions}}
  {{partial 'collection_form'}}
{{else}}
  <p>loading, for kicks</p>
{{/else}}
```

Comment: is it only selects that are slow? or is it all form controls in general?

Comment: In my tests, the `{{view Ember.Select}}` helpers were always to blame. Try commenting them out of the templates to see if things speed up. Then slowly add them in and profile with your inspector.

Comment: I was only hoping to add some sort of "loading" indication to the user when the DOM lags, just for the user experience.  I will not be able to get around the select helpers.  Do you still think there is an option for this? ..even if I cant solve the slow rendering?

Comment: Nope. This is going to be a problem not only when it loads, but every time you transition to and from that route. Again, you need to get your brain away from the whole idea of this being a "loading" issue. The data is there, it's your browser (and your CPU, memory, etc.) that is causing the page to freeze while it renders the data. That make sense? You need to address how those selects are even being generated.

Comment: Yes that seems a little more clear now. Thanks.  I see the update to your answer, and already my mind is considering stuff like maybe a wizard-style form or somehow only presenting a few options at a time...

Comment: I just updated the answer with an approach that may work for you. You still need to write most of the code, but that pattern will give you full control over how many options will render on the page. You could recursively push options into `generatedOptions` every 500ms or something. Good luck!